# Digital experience builder main page not showing

Tags: force.com-sites, community-builder, digital-experience

I had created a site in my production org but the landing page(Home), which has to be a standard lightning experience page(main) is not shown in the pop-up. It's just showing default. What should I do to get standard  the main page?
[image]

I have a lightning page called main in my sandbox but I cannot find that in my production. Only based on this does the customer community's home page feature has to be decided to be as default page or lightning page. Please see below image for sandbox

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "Home"?

Comment: Yes The home page @phil W

Comment: What if you search for "home" instead of "main"? Is this not the page you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please publish your site and then try again
Go to --> All Sites --> Builder --> Home Setting --> Page Variation --> check status. If the page is not published, then publish it and again

[image]

Thanks,
Lavanya